# Я новичок в Python, поэтому я не понимаю ошибки

Tags: python

```
h=6.67*10**-11

m=("Введите массу планеты(в кг):",float(input()))

j=("Введите радиус планеты:",int(input()))


b=("Введите высоту(в км):",int(input()))

g=h*(m/((j+b)*(j+b)))

print(g)
```

Всплывает данная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "e", line 5, in <module>


    g=h*(m/((j+b)*(j+b)))

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сохраняется кортеж а не значение, да и странный синтаксис ввода имхо...
Так будет работать

```py
h=6.67*10**-11

m=float(input("Введите массу планеты(в кг):"))
j=int(input("Введите радиус планеты:"))
b=int(input("Введите высоту(в км):"))

g=h*(m/((j+b)*(j+b)))

print(g)
```

А в m у вас лежит не число, а вот это: `('Введите массу планеты(в кг):', 12.0)`.
`12` в данном случае - введенное число.